# select -Property with string array and customized column script block?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script.

```
$cols = Get-MyColumns # returns "a","b","c",...
$cols2 = $cols, @{n='x'; e={"0"}} # Add a new column
import-csv test.csv | select -property $cols2
```

However the script gets the following error.

```
select : Cannot convert System.Object[] to one of the following types {System.String, 
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:1 char:xx
+ Import-Csv test.csv | select -Property $cols2
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

The string array cannot be concatenated with the customized column definition. What's the workaround of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you calculated property you need to delimit the `Name` and `Expression` with a semi colon. You also need to combine the "fields" so they are passed as one-dimensional array to the `-Property` parameter.

```
select -Property ($cols + @{n='x';e={0}})
```

Property expects a single string or an array. Changing the definition for `$cols` would also have worked

```
$cols = "a","b","c",@{n='x';e={"0"}}
```

If you don't care about the value of the new column you can just put in whatever to create a null column.

```
$cols = "a","b","c","doesnotexist"
```

For example:

```
a b c doesnotexist
- - - ------------
1 2 3             
4 5 6
```

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 your update does not follow what I was suggesting. Does `$cols2 = $cols + @{n='x'; e={"0"}}` work?.... and your comment is gone it seems.

Comment: I tried `e={"0"}` and it still gets the same error.

Comment: It's not the quotes. I'm sure its how PowerShell is combining your array and the calculated expression. Let me try an update.

Comment: Interesting I changed `$cols2 = $cols,@{n='x';e={"0"}}` to `$cols2 = $cols + @{n='x';e={"0"}}` and it seems working now.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 that is what my first code snippet was trying to show you.

Comment: I guess `$col, i` creates `@(@($col), i)` while `$col + i` append `i` to `$col`.